# Javascript variable into postdata of jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Right now I have this `postData: { search: function() { return $("#search").val(); },},`

I then have jQuery function above the jqGrid function that performs some logic and produces a string variable. Right now I am just taking that variable and setting the value of the search element like this:

```
$("#startSearch").click(function() {

  $("#search").val(searchVal);

   $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");

});
```

This works but I was hopping to do this differently. I want to just pass the seachVal variable that my jQuery function produces right into the postdata.

I tried it like this but its not working postData: `{ search: function() { return searchVal; },},`

I'm getting an error that says searchVal is not defined. I made sure that the searchVal variable is global but it is still not working.

Is this possible or am I just looking at this wrong?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Here is a stripped down version of the page:

```
<fieldset>
<input type='text' id='search' />
<button type='button' id='startSearch'>Search</button>
</fieldset>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

            $("#startSearch").click(function() {

                serchVal = 'transID > "5"';

                $("#search").val(serchVal);

                $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");


            });


      $("#list").jqGrid({

        url:'data.cfc?method=gridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',

        jsonReader : {
         root: "rows",
         page: "currentpage",
         total: "totalpages",
         records: "totalrecords",
         repeatitems: false,
         id: "0",
       },

      postData: { search: function() { return $("#search").val(); },},      

        colModel :[ 
          {name:'transid', label:'Trans ID', width:60}, 
          {name:'companyname', label:'Company Name', width:245},
          {name:'companycode', label:'Company Code', width:245},
          {name:'datasource', label:'Datasource', width:245}

        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowList:[10,50,100],
        rowNum:'10',
        height:221,
        sortname: 'transid',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Get Trans',
        altRows: false,
        autowidth: true,
        forceFit: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        scroll: false,
        sortable: true

      });       

      $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,view:true}); 

    }); 

</script>

    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: To understand your question one need to know *where you define* the variable `searchVal` and *where and when you assign* the value to it. So more full code is required.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I just updated my question with more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem exist just because you didn't declared the variable `serchVal` (you means probably `searchVal`). You can try to modify the code to the following

```
$(function () {
    var searchVal = '';

    $("#startSearch").click(function () {
        searchVal = 'transID > "5"';
        $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });

    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: 'data.cfc?method=gridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        jsonReader : {
            page: "currentpage",
            total: "totalpages",
            records: "totalrecords",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
        postData: { search: function () { return searchVal; }},
        colModel: [
            {name: 'transid', label: 'Trans ID', width: 60},
            {name: 'companyname', label: 'Company Name', width: 245},
            {name: 'companycode', label: 'Company Code', width: 245},
            {name: 'datasource', label: 'Datasource', width: 245}
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowList: [10, 50, 100],
        rowNum: 10,
        height: 221,
        sortname: 'transid',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Get Trans',
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortable: true
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
        {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, view: true});
});
```

After that you can remove `<input type='text' id='search' />`.

Comment: Yes, that did it. It makes sense to me now. I was trying it different ways but now I see I needed to declare the variable outside of the click event. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just wrap your logic in a function

```
function SomeLogic() { 
   return("some logic here!");
}
```

which is going to be called like this:

```
postData: { search: function() { return SomeLogic() } },
```

so you just have to reload the grid

```
$("#startSearch").click(function() {
   $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

obviously your function SomeLogic can just return **searchVal**

```
function SomeLogic() { 
   return(searchVal);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help LeftX. I tried it like this but it's still not working. The grid function still cannot access the SomeLogic function. I am doing something wrong.